# use taxonomy terms as values for radio buttons by code

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

I've built a function for select / checkboxes but I can't get it working for radio buttons.

```
/**
 * helper function to get taxonomy term options for select widget
 * @arguments 
 * @return array of select options for form
 */
function popover_get_tax_term_options($machine_name){
    //$options = array( '0' => '');

    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name)->vid;

    $options_source = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);

    foreach($options_source as $item ) {
        $key = $item->tid;
        $value = $item->name;
        $options[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Calling this in a form hook works with: ( shows all terms )

```
$form['third']['field_functioncat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => 'Functiecategorie',
    '#options' => popover_get_tax_term_options('functie_categorie'),
);
```

But when I call it with radio it doesn't work: ( only shows the title with 1 radio button )

```
 $form['third']['field_functioncat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => 'Functiecategorie',
    '#options' => popover_get_tax_term_options('functie_categorie'),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm why didn't I see this... I used `radio` instead of `radios`.

Changed the code and now it works:

```
$form['third']['field_functioncat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Functiecategorie',
    '#options' => popover_get_tax_term_options('functie_categorie'),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#options
```

values must be in array: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#options

example:

```
'#options' => array(
            0 => t('None'),
            1 => t('Team'),
            2 => t('Business'),
            3 => t('Talent'),
        ),
```

Comment: did you even read the question? In my question the values returned to `#options` **is** an array and besides that the answer is within my question...